# 302 .htaccess redirect on joomla 1.5

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla1.5

What's the best way to temporary redirect my entire site to a subdomain in joomla?
For example redirect `mydomain.com` (including all my website pages) to `offline.mydomain.com`.

What string should I add in .htaccess?

I want to be sure that all visitors are not able to visit `mydomain.com` and all subfolder and files when redirect is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place a .htacces with following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteRule (.*) http://offline.mydomain.com/? [R=302,L]
```

so everybody except the User with IP 127.0.0.1 will get redirected by it.

Comment: Can I set redirect by ip? All visitor ip addresses are redirect except my ip.